# the query returns duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, opencart

I am trying to write a script that shows additional products for particular product in an internet store. Products shown based on price and category. For example if you are chosen motherboard script will show additional product to it hard discs coolers ets.  Price range must be specified by administrator. The problem is that the code returns duplicate products. I have tried to use group by, distinct in MySQL query. Also I have tried to use array-unique function in PHP. Neither didn't work. What could be possible solution for this problem? Now the code looks as follows.

```
if(isset($product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2'])) {
    $i=1;
                        $imax = 5;
                        while ($i < $imax) {
$product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
FROM oc_product p
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
GROUP BY pc.product_id
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 0 , 10");                        if(isset($product_sql_test2->row['product_id'])){$this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] = $product_sql_test2->row['product_id'];}
$i++;
}
}
```

Comment: how are you fetching the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
GROUP BY product_id
```

or like

```
GROUP BY p.product_id

pc.product_id AS product_id
```

change this to

```
pc.product_id AS p_id
```

and try to group like

```
GROUP BY p_id
```

Comment: When I try to group by product id I get the following error: Notice: Error: Column 'product_id' in group statement is ambiguous if I try group by product p.product_id I get the duplicate data.

Comment: pc.product_id AS product_id change this to pc.product_id AS p_id and try to group like GROUP BY p_id

Comment: Still getting duplicate data.